# how disable resume hard disk from Sleep on Shut Down

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, shutdown, window, keepalive

I'm using Windows 7 , I set my drive to sleep after 10 minutes and it works but, when I shut down windows my hard drive resume from sleep. Why? It shouldn't keep hard drive sleep and shut down the PC ?

Comment: Sleep for a harddrive only means it's not being used *right at that moment*. The system is still holding open file references, caches, the registry, the disk journal-- all of which must be cleaned up and closed.

Comment: If the OS is putting the disk to sleep, it should have flushed all unwritten data to disk.

Answer (score 2):

When you shut down Windows, various things are written to disk, swap file is modified, etc.  If the disk is asleep, those items can not be written or modified on the disk, which is why the disk is powered up before the system is shut down.

Comment: I turn off the option to write the debug information and the option to write events in the registry. I disabled also the paging file because I have 16GB. The first hard disk is an OCZ SSD, the other harddrive that i'm using is for data and these still wakeup before I turn off my PC.

Comment: I'm guessing that the other drive's sleep state isn't the same as the shutdown state, so it probably has to power back up before it shuts down, and that's ignoring any file system activity that might have to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Because it needs to wake up the harddisk to save user and system settings. Otherwise your settings (and all ongoing works in that session) will be lost.